# cv2 videowriter, writes fine, but throws error when application closes

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, mp4

This is a minor inconvenience really. the application runs as expected, but when I close out the application `OpenCV` throws an error only then.

I'm taking a data file, that contains several hundred frames and merging them into a video file. Here are the steps I take.

```
def createMovie(self):
    print("CREATE Movie")

    fileName = self.generateFilename()

    minV = self._data.min()
    maxV = self._data.max()

    nFrames = self._data.nframes
    width, height = self._data.frame().shape[0], self._data.frame().shape[1]
    fps = 16

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP44')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(fileName, fourcc, float(fps), (width, height))

    for frame in range(nFrames):
        myImg = self._data.frame(frame)
        global_norm = np.true_divide((myImg - minV), (maxV - minV))
        norm = (global_norm * 255)
        intNorm = norm.astype(int)

        rotated = cv2.rotate(intNorm, cv2.cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
        flipped = cv2.flip(rotated, 0)
        temp = np.uint8(flipped)

        out.write(temp)
        
    out.release()
```

as you can see I'm normalizing the frame data as part of the global min/max related to the frames. I'm writing the video file as an mp4, so I can use either the `MP44` or `MP42` `fourcc` codec.

before leaving the function I make sure to release the video writer. Which I have verified occurs with the `isopen()` call.

All frames are written to the video file with no issues. Playback works and no errors are thrown, until!

Until I close the application. I'm using `pyqt5` to develop the GUI. When I click on the close button, I get this error.

> OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x3434504d/'MP44' is not found (format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)')'

or

> OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x3234504d/'MP42' is not supported with codec id 15 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
> [mp4 @ 000002e39f4769c0] Could not find tag for codec msmpeg4v2 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container

I've tried any number of other codecs, but the `MP44` or `MP42` were the only ones that allowed me to write to mp4. Yes, I need to write the file as an mp4. Other options created a viable file, but threw an error at runtime, failed to write a viable file but did not throw an error, or failed to write the file and threw an error.

codecs tried: mp4v, avc1, avc3, hev1, hvc1, mp44, mp42

I can live with this error, I would just prefer to understand what's happening and clean up the code. There is no other use of `OpenCV` anywhere else in the application. So I'm curious as to why it only throws the error at the end when I close out the application.

Comment: what is `MP44` supposed to be? weird fourcc. what's the file name? `.mp4` containers can't carry just any codec. by specification, they're limited. it specifically says **codec not currently supported in container**. have you tried `avc1`? that's H.264. list all the fourccs you *did* try. people hate guessing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I've updated my post with the codecs I've tried.  Also I can't find where I saw mp44 as an option, but I've used it and it saves the video, unlike the other codecs I attempted.  yes avc1 fails

Answer (score 0):

Reading its documentation, opencv installs FFmpeg binaries in its site-packages folder (OPENCV_SOURCE_CODE/3rdparty/ffmpeg/). What might be happening in your application is that the included FFmpeg build does not come with these 2 codecs that you want to use and somehow falling back to an available compatible codec (likely 'h264'), and saving the FFmpeg error message till the very end. So try 'h264' or @Christoph Rackwitz's suggestion of 'avcl' to see if the error goes away.

(shameless plug) if you wish to do this with my [ffmpegio](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/) library, you can try the following (after properly installing FFmpeg to your system):

```py
import ffmpegio

def createMovie(self):
    print("CREATE Movie")

    fileName = self.generateFilename() # assume it ends with '.mp4'

    minV = self._data.min()
    maxV = self._data.max()

    nFrames = self._data.nframes
    fps = 16

    with ffmpegio.open(fileName, 'wv', rate=fps, vf='vflip,hflip,transpose') as out:

        for frame in range(nFrames):
            myImg = self._data.frame(frame)
            norm = np.true_divide((myImg - minV), (maxV - minV))
            out.write(norm.astype('f4')) # float32 grayscale image
```

I believe the `vflip`-`hflip`-`transpose` combo does what you are intended to do, but please double check.

FFmpeg has pix_fmt='grayf32le' which is a floating-point grayscale with pixel values defined between 0.0 and 1.0.

You can add `show_log=True` to the `open` command to see the FFmpeg log (the ffmpegio's error handling is abysmal right now).

Also, you can add `overwrite=True` to let FFmpeg overwrite previous run (or equivalently `y=None` to set the FFmpeg flag directly).

This library is still very young and needs testing. If you encounter any errors, please report on the GitHub Issues.

Comment: hello, thanks for the input. I see what you're saying and I assumed as much as well. I've updated my post to include the other codecs I've tried.  

as for ffmpeqio. I would be interested, I couldn't find any examples for turning images into a video stream. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include how to use ffmpegio for your code.

Comment: Are your images in grayscale?

Comment: Yes, they are grayscale.

Comment: OK. I've changed my code to shave off a couple more lines of yours. `ffmpegio` automatically recognizes `pix_fmt=grayf32le` if you write single-precision floating-point numpy arrays.

Comment: One more thing. If you can retrieve all your images as 3d array (nframes x height x width) then you don't need the `for` loop and just normalize the array then do `out.write(norm_3d_array)`

Comment: ffmpegio uses a subprocess. I'm not a fan of that. -- if you want a proper wrapper that calls the library's APIs, look at PyAV. that does it properly.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - That's fine, but if you want to promote PyAV, why don't you post an answer demonstrating how to use it for Michael's purpose. (I'm actually very curious of your solution as I just recently learned about PyAV.)